# Hibernate JPA scenario to solve?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, hibernate-mapping

There is a class Consultant. A consultant can have many kind of experience like salaried, self-employed, freelancer. For each type of experience there are different data to save in database.

### Salaried:

Total Experience
Company Name
Experience Time in years
Offer/Reveling letter Link

### Self Employed:

Company Name
Total Experience
CIN_Number
GST_Number
CompanyCertificateLinkUrl

### FreeLancer:

Total Experience

A user can have experience in more than one occupation type like a consultant is both salaried and freelancer, or self employed plus salaried and freelancer. So i am confused how to make the @Entity class for this type of use case.

> My Solution

```
@Entity
class Consultant{

@Id
int id;

@OneToOne
Salaried semp;

@OneToOne
SelfEmployed selfemp;

@OneToOne
Freelancer femp;
}
```

But i think this is not good practice as it will lead to many null field in the database.

## ANY BETTER SOLUTION

Comment: design looks strange to me: A consultant could have worked for multiple companies... I cannot understand the semantics behind the `OneToOne`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach is fine. `@OneToOne` fields are optional by default, so can be null. That means there wouldn't be a row in the corresponding tables, so you'd only have up to two null values per row in the Consultant table.

If you're really concerned about nulls in the database, then you can map the relationships the other way, so:

```
@Entity
class Consultant{

    @Id
    int id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "consultant")
    Salaried semp;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "consultant")
    SelfEmployed selfemp;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "consultant")
    Freelancer femp;
}
```

This way, if there's no row in the Salaried table that's related to the Consultant, the `semp` field will be null in the `Consultant` object.

Comment: I'll surely try this.

Answer (score 0):

you can do with two classes **`consultant`** and **`profession`**(id,name) and the relation `OneToMany`,`ManyToOne`

**Consultant's entity**

```
@Entity
class Consultant{

    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "consultant",cascade = CascadeType.All)
    List<ConsultantProfession> cp;

}
```

**Profession's entity**

```
@Entity
class Profession{

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profession", cascade = CascadeType.All)
    private List<ConsultantProfession> cp;

}
```

**ConsultantProfession's entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="consultant_profession")
public class ConsultantProfession{

    @Id
    private int id;

    // this is the link to the consultant class
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="consultant_id")
    private Consultant consultant; // this name is specified in the class seeing patients as value of parameter `mappedBy`

    // this is the link to the profession class

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="profession_id") 
    private Profession profession;

}
```

Comment: I'll surely try this.

Comment: how and where will i add my other fields for the other type of profession in this solution?

Comment: give one example.

Comment: like in ques i said each profession has different fields., where to add those fields.?

Comment: considering the approach you took just above it would be fine, otherwise in this case you will have to create another domain entity then linked to profession and it also depends on what kind of relationship.